# Get selected item from databound ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms

This may be something very simple.
If:

```
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
listBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
listBox.DataSource = bindingList1;
```

How can I get the string representing selected `DisplayMamber`? I can get `SelectedValue` for `ValueMamber`, but how do I get that `DisplayMember` value/string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
listBox1.Text
```

Gets or searches for the text of the currently selected item in the ListBox. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.text(v=vs.110).aspx)